# Find all the permutations $ \tau $ such that $ \tau(1)=1 $

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> $$
>   \sigma =
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14  \\
>     7& 5& 2& 6& 4& 3& 10& 13& 11& 9& 1& 8& 14& 12 \\
>    \end{pmatrix}
>   $$
> Let $\sigma \in S_{14}$ and $\langle \sigma \rangle =:H$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $S_{14}$.
> Find all the $\tau \in H$ such that $\tau(1)=1$.

Hello everyone, I found many exercises on the Symmetric Groups $S_n$ like this one i wrote above.

I first write $\sigma$ as product of his cycles: $\sigma=(1\hspace{1mm} 7\hspace{1mm} 10\hspace{1mm} 9\hspace{1mm} 11)(2\hspace{1mm} 5\hspace{1mm} 4\hspace{1mm} 6\hspace{1mm} 3)(8\hspace{1mm} 13\hspace{1mm} 14\hspace{1mm} 12) $. Since the cardinality of $H$ is equal to the order of $\sigma$, then his cardinality is equal to the $lcm(5,5,4)=20$, where $"5,5,4"$ are the lengths of the cycles of $\sigma$.

***I have many doubts about this below:***

So, if $H=\{\sigma^i | i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ I can just write the powers of $\sigma$ (and this is very painful) and I will have a certain power, suppose $\sigma^5$, where $\sigma(1)=1$ and then  in all the other powers between $5$ and $20$ (that is the order of $\sigma$) I will have $\sigma(1)=1$.

I would really appreciate some help.

P.s: sorry for my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You   want $\tau=\sigma^r$ to fix $1$; clearly, from the expression for $\sigma$ as  a product of disjoint cycles only $\sigma^{5s}$ will do this. That is $\tau=e,\sigma^5, \sigma^{10},\sigma^{15}$, or $\tau=e, (8\ 13\ 14\ 12), (8\ 14)(13\ 12), (8\ 12\ 14\ 13)$.

I don't think it's very painful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Yes it's actually not painful, i wrote that because i was thinking about another way to do this but it was very inefficient.